# No space between each of the Gallery Images

Tags: xamarin, android-imageview, android-gallery, overlapping, android-bitmap

In Xamarin, how can I have a specified space between each of my images in my gallery?

Here is my code for the ImageAdapter:

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView i = new ImageView (context);

    var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(imageURIs[position]);
    i.SetImageBitmap(GetImageThumbnailFromBitmap(imageBitmap, thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight));

    i.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.FitCenter);

    return i;
}
```

Each of the images are overlapping each other. How can I specify a certain space between each of the displayed images?

Can I please have some help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can apply spacing between your images by setting the padding attributes on the `ImageView`.

Padding attributes control the amount of spacing between the image content and the views border. The attributes for this are `PaddingStart`, `PaddingEnd`, `PaddingLeft`, `PaddingRight`, `PaddingTop` and `PaddingBottom`. EG:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView();
image.PaddingLeft = 15; // Adds 15 pixels of space between the views border and the image content.
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  1) The PaddingLeft attribute is read only in Xamarin Android and there is a function called SetPadding which seemed to be the one to call, but did not do anything.